# sending message in android two times instead of once

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sendmessage, smsmanager

I want to send SMS after call ends, my app sends the SMS but the problem is that it is sending it twice in every call and I don't know where the problem is (I want to send one sms every time not twice)

Here is my code:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
  SmsManager smsmanager=SmsManager.getDefault(); 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  if (phoneNumber != null){

     telephonyService.endCall();
     smsmanager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "message", null, null);

  }
}
```

on Manifest:

```
<receiver  android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: How is your `Receiver ` registerer? With which`IntentFilter`?

Comment: @SimonMarquis i added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Receiver` will be called every time the phone state changes (ringing, in call, ...).
You must filter the corresponding action:

```
  // Keep track of the previous state
  String previousState;

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (CALL_STATE_IDLE.equals(state) && CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(previousState) {
      // send sms here
    }
    previousState = state;
  }
```

Comment: tank u soooo much , with a little change of your code it works, thanx :) @SimonMarquis